# Classical Inheritance Divergence

Tags: inheritance, architecture, paradigms

I'm wondering what should be done in the case of needing Roles or Traits but in a classical inheritance environment. I have stemming of a class down two roads, both of which stem from a root class, however, I want to link the diverged classes on the two roads together to share the same functionality. See below:

```
+-- Base
 +-- Base_Processor
 | +-- Base_Processor_Request
 |  +-- Base_Processor_Request_Ajax
 +-- Base_Impl
  +-- Base_Impl_MyImpl
   +-- Base_Impl_MyImpl_Processor (extends from Base_Processor)
    +-- Base_Impl_MyImpl_Processor_Request (extends from ??)
     +-- Base_Impl_MyImpl_Processor_Request_Ajax (extends from ??)
```

What would be the best way to link Base_Impl_MyImpl_Processor_Request and Base_Processor_Request together while still extending from Base_Impl_MyImpl_Processor, and also link Base_Impl_MyImpl_Processor_Request_Ajax in the same fashion.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Prefer Composition Over Inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree 100% with [Alex Burtsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235715/alex-burtsev)'s comment - that many levels of inheritance looks like a dependency nightmare (and, as you're discovering, rather difficult to reuse particular bits of code across classes when you use inheritance that much).

Typically I wouldn't expect *trait* classes to be plugged into a heirarchy - to my mind, traits are standalone concepts which define variations across implementation details, and therefore only belong to an interface rather than being derived from a base class

If this is existing code and you have multiple elements which you need to reuse among different derived classes, I think it would make more sense to split those out to separate classes which are not related to your heirarchy at all.

It would seem that `Processor`, `Request` and `Ajax` could better serve you as separate entities.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, but you're saying I should make those into interfaces, and not reuse code across Base and Impl, correct? But they will both implement the same interfaces. Thanks for your response, by the way!

Comment: Nevermind. Figured out what you mean [Composition versus Inheritance](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh.html) Thanks!